# Jquery effects not working when using ckeditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, contenteditable

I'm using `contenteditable="true"` and ckeditor inline to edit my html pages, but when I use ckeditor or just add ckeditor libraries in my page, other jQuery effects (like jQuery tabs) stop working.
I tried `config.allowedContent = true;` but it doesn't help me.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Could you share some code to make the issue reproducible?